# My contact form is not working, doesn´t display any error but email are not being sent.

Tags: php, forms, email, post

My contact form is not working, I can´t make it send the message and it is not displaying any error.

This is my php file:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
empty($_POST['email'])     ||
empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
empty($_POST['message'])   ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

$to = 'email@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website 
contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: 
$email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@mydomain.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>'
```

Comment: Are you sure `mail()` is set up, and working on your server? What IS your server? VM? Shared hosting? Something else?

Comment: Try to use PHPMailer with gmail SMTP, http://subinsb.com/send-mails-via-smtp-server-gmail-outlook-php,   read this page too https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp

Comment: Have you checked the spambox?

Comment: @K.Tromp already did and nothing

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie already checked and it is there, just emailed my hosting provider to see whats wrong.

Comment: @webDev ok will do. I'll let you know how did it go. Thanks!